# Reading data from .xlsb in Clojure

Tags: clojure, xlsb

How can I read data from `.xlsb` file in Clojure? I have tried `incanter.excel` which uses `apache.poi` which doesn't support binary format. I have seen some examples of reading `.xlsb` in Java using `ODBC` but as far as I understand `JDBC-ODBC` bridge was removed in Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just added a read-only streaming reader for xlsb files on Apache POI.  It will be available with 3.16-beta3.