# reading XLSB from apache poi

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xlsb

I've read it stated on multiple SO questions that Apache POI 3.16-beta3 has read-only support for xlsb files.

I am using poi 3.17 and cannot find any documentation or examples of this feature.  The best I can find is an example of extracting raw text only via XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor, but this appears to be quite old (2010?) and I am unsure if this is the referenced capability.

Is there any documentation or examples of using poi to read xlsb files with the read-only parsing alluded to in the comments of this question: [Exception reading XLSB File Apache POI java.io.CharConversionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282164/exception-reading-xlsb-file-apache-poi-java-io-charconversionexception#14286113) and in an answer to this: [Reading data from .xlsb in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802957/reading-data-from-xlsb-in-clojure) by Tim Allison ?

Answer (score 2):

The functionality that Tim was referring to is actually `XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor`, and it was added in Apache POI 3.16. It can be used to extract text-content from the file.

There is currently no functionality to fully read the file content, though.

See also the [JavaDoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/extractor/XSSFEventBasedExcelExtractor.html) for this class.